# How are socket.io session ids generated?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

If I look at the network log of the websockets, the socket.io client connects to an URL like this: `ws://domain:port/socket.io/1/websocket/SESSION_ID`

But how is the SESSION_ID generated by the client, at the end of the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like ultimately, it's generated in engine.io ([here](https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io/blob/d11e17c8d7c09b9f0dbc4b0df72c6f6914aa68bc/lib/server.js#L233)), which uses the [`base64id`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64id) package.

Comment: The client connects to this URL. How the client knows it, if only the server generates the id?

Comment: Without diving too deep into `socket.io`, I assume that the server sends the id to the client as part of the connection setup protocol.